# Search Product using GTIN Number in admin order while Adding New Product in order Manually from backend in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, field, product

I want to search Product using product GTIN number in the admin order product search while adding new products manually in order.

I attached Screenshot Where I Want to search using product GTIN number in admin order.

Can Anyone Help Me How Can I achieve this ?

Field to add: 
meta:product_hwk

[image]

Comment: I added my question separatly can you give solution for above scenario @mujuonly

Comment: I want to override wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-search/lib/ext/class-wps-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php file in child theme. how can i override it @mujuonly